# fdisk not showing partition, parted does

Tags: partitioning, mount, fdisk, parted

I just noticed when doing a `fdisk -l /dev/sdl` that my partition is not shown:

```
Disk /dev/sdl: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

`blkid` output shows all my other drives have paritions listed:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="ee2faccf-1f90-4f40-baf5-b32f9048c2d3" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="a0456ffd-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="fzafOi-iMIf-RvNZ-9LQy-tmsy-q4Tm-bdjMoC" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="a0456ffd-05"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="c50ee65b-cfc0-43cf-94df-c1db4c38e032" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="ca4a8633-0fc8-43fd-96e8-9e69bf3a6931"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="23943443-a533-4b4f-b5a3-9b4aecb5859f" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="2b52aba3-17d3-4688-b2d6-4c8e326afd6b"
/dev/sdd1: UUID="f0d9779a-21c2-49a1-83da-1ae71dbaa8b1" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="a2ecc2a1-50c4-4dbb-bae4-7b4fa1d6ed91"
/dev/sdl: UUID="ac3bfba8-049a-4ace-83c6-2749422211f1" TYPE="ext4"
```

Parted shows there is a partition on the drive:

```
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdl
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Model: ATA WDC WD30EFRX-68E (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdl: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
1      0.00B  3001GB  3001GB  ext4
```

`partprobe -s /dev/sdl`

```
/dev/sdl: loop partitions 1
```

The drive mounts fine when using the UUID of the drive ("ac3bfba8-049a-4ace-83c6-2749422211f1"). Normally I would be using the UUID of the partition in /etc/fstab

Any ideas why this has happened and how to rectify it?

Comment: Did you run `mkfs` on `/dev/sdl` without creating a partition table on it?

Comment: possibly. If I did is there anything I can do?

Comment: Other than {backup data, create partition table, create and format partition}, I don't think so. Does it make a difference though? If you don't want to add partitions, and the disk works fine (which I believe it should), you can carry on like this.

Comment: I remember that fdisk does not work with partitions with more than 2TB.

Comment: @Mitsu García - my other 3TB drives show up just fine. I think muru is probably correct and I must have issued mkfs on the drive not on the partition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your disk is not partitioned; it's being used "raw." You can tell this from the following `blkid` output from your original post:

```
/dev/sdl: UUID="ac3bfba8-049a-4ace-83c6-2749422211f1" TYPE="ext4"
```

Note the device identifier is `/dev/sdl`, which includes no partition number. This contrasts with the output for your other disks' partitions, which do include numbers (`/dev/sda1`, for instance).

`parted` calls the partition table type "loop," which is another clue about this.

It's perfectly legal to use a disk in this way; however, it can be confusing. If you've not yet stored much data on the disk, you might want to create one or more partitions on it to avoid future confusion. (A script or some other tool might assume that a disk is partitioned, which could cause serious problems.) OTOH, if you've already filled a significant part of that 3TB capacity, backing it up might be too much hassle, and using it as-is might be the best course of action.

Comment: I marked your response as correct, @muru has already pointed this out and explained what caused the issue. Unfortunately he replied as a comment so I couldn't give him the credit.